# mysql update with select same table

Tags: mysql, select, updates

I am going update table Transaction

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `amount` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `rate` decimal(9,7) NOT NULL default '0.0000000',
  `amount1` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


INSERT INTO `transaction` (`id`, `amount`, `rate`, `amount1`, `date_time`) VALUES
(1, 100.00, 0.8000000, 80.00, '2015-02-03 16:56:58'),
(2, 100.00, 0.7820000, 78.20, '2015-02-04 01:45:24');
```

my final result needs to be:

```
(1, 100.00, 0.7600000, 76.00, '2015-02-03 16:56:58'),
(2, 100.00, 0.7429000, 74.29, '2015-02-04 01:45:24');
```

I've try to update the column rate with this query

select rate *0,95 from transaction

but

```
update transaction set rate = (select rate *0,95 from transaction where <Date_time_condition>) where <Date_time_condition>
```

don't work
after this change the amount1 = amount * rate

Comment: Is it because you use a comma instead of a period as a decimal separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```js
update transaction set rate = rate * 0.95 where <Datetime condition>
```

Comment: A more refined form is given by Gordon Linoff. You should follow that for better readability and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the condition is not correlated with the outer table, then you can move the subquery to a `join` clause:

```
update transaction t cross join
       (select rate *0,95 as newrate from transaction where <Date_time_condition>) val
    set t.rate = val.newrate
    where <Date_time_condition>;
```

However, you might not need the subquery at all.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
update transaction t
    set t.rate = 0.95 * t.rate
    where <Date_time_condition>;
```

Comment: Tnk Linoff, I've try your solution

update transaction t cross join
       (select rate *0,95 as newrate from transaction) val
    set t.rate = val.newrate

but the column rate is for alla records 76.00 :(
OT how can I formating the code to show frendly?

Answer (score 0):

```
update transaction set rate = (select (rate *0.95) as result 
from transaction where <Date_time_condition>) where <Date_time_condition>
```